Why is the generator voltage in phase with current?
The figure shows a toy model for power transmission using ideal transfomers.
In this model, the phase angle between the voltage across the load and the current is zero.
Let's take the load voltage as the reference, i.e., \$  \tilde{V}_{L}=30V \angle 0°\$. The load is resistive, so the current is in phase with the load, i.e., \$ \tilde{I}_{L}=1A\angle 0°\$.
Therefore, the current in the transmission wires is going to be \$ \tilde{I}_{T}=0.5A\angle0°\$ and the voltage across the primary of the second step down transformer is \$\tilde{V}_{p2}=100V\angle0°\$.
Applying KVL in the loop between the two transformers, one concludes that \$\tilde{V}_{s1} =100V\angle0°+0.5A(20\Omega)\angle0°=110V\angle0°\$.
Therefore, \$\tilde{V}_{p1}=220V\angle0°\$ and \$\tilde{I}_{G}=0.25A\angle0°\$
How could this be the case? Assuming everything is ideal, shouldn't the magnetizing current, \$\tilde{I}_{G}\$ in this case, lag the voltage \$\tilde{V}_{p1}\$ by a \$\frac{\pi}{2}\$ angle?
Reference of the figure:
I made it myself


One version of an ideal transformer has infinite magnetization inductance. Which one are you assuming?

@Andyaka I am not aware of this difference.

An ideal transformer, as the term 'ideal' is used here, has infinite magnetizing inductance and zero leakage inductance. As such, there is no phase shift between the primary and secondary, so if the load on the secondary is purely resistive, the load presented by the primary will also be purely resistive.
Even in the case of a non-ideal transformer, the current wouldn't lag by π/2. There would be an inductive term to it from finite leakage and magnetizing inductances, but (for reasonably good transformers) the impedance seen by the source would still be primarily real. After all, the source has to provide real power for the load to consume real power!

You're saying that the phase shift between the primary current of first transformer and the primary voltage is one quarter out of phase in the no load condition. However, when the secondary of the second transformer is loaded by a resistive load, that phase shift drops to zero?

@Jack For an ideal transformer, the phase shift would not exist in the no-load condition, because the primary current would be zero. For a real transformer, yes, the phase shift would change drastically depending on the load. It would never be an ideal π/2 or 0, though.

But the magnetizing current lags the source voltage by 90° angle in the no load condition? Doesn't it?

@Jack Not in a real transformer, because there's some resistance to the winding as well. It'll be close to 90° though. And not in an ideal transformer either, because the phase of zero current is undefined.

The current isn't zero though in an ideal transfomer. It is small but not zero. Enough to magnetize the core.

@Jack Define what you mean by ideal, then, because my definition of an ideal transformer has infinite magnetizing inductance and draws zero current when unloaded.

I mean the one that takes a small current to magnetize the core when unloaded

Then sure, if you have finite magnetizing inductance and/or leakage inductance, but still zero resistance, then yes, it'll be 90° when unloaded.

So, my original statement is right? My first comment?

@Jack No, because if you have finite magnetizing or leakage inductance in your transformer, the current phase won't be exactly zero when loaded by a resistor alone.

So what went wrong in the calculation in my question?

@Jack You never took into account the finite inductances.

So, the calculation I have curried out assumed the version of the ideal transfomer where the inductance is infinite?

@Jack Specifically, where the leakage inductance is zero and the magnetizing inductance is infinite.

Thank you very much for your help.
